# push few argument into vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I want to know if there is shorter way to push two arguments into vector

```
std::vector<vector> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
```

I want to write those two push_back lines in one line.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think you meant vector<int> did you not?

Comment: I believe this problem is different because the OP asks to do it in "one line" @MartijnPieters

Comment: @NL628 the OP has accepted an answer that was nothing more than a link to the other question; I took it as an indication that the other post was sufficient.